# iOS NSString stringWithString cause memory leak when using ARC

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsstring, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I want to pass some data when posting notification, the data is a dictionary containing the local notification information.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
NSString *uuid = [NSString stringWithString:notification.userInfo[@"UUID"]];
NSDictionary *infoDic = @{
                          @"UUID" :uuid
                          };
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"PopReminder"
     object:nil
     userInfo:infoDic];
}
```

}

The notification is like `notification.userInfo = @{ @"UUID" : list.itemKey }`.

And list.itemKey is a string to identify the specific list.

`NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] init];
 NSString *key = [uuid UUIDString];
 list.itemKey = key;`

But when test using Leak, it showed a NSString object causing memory leak. How can a class method will cause memory leak and it's using ARC. Can someone help to find the solution for it? Thanks.

[image]

**Solved in another way, but still unclear about the leak reason:**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
NSString *uuid;
NSArray *lists = [YYList MR_findAll];
for (YYList *list in lists) {
    if ([list.itemKey isEqualToString:notification.userInfo[@"UUID"]]) {
        uuid = [list.itemKey copy];
    }
}
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"PopReminder"
     object:nil
     userInfo:@{
                @"UUID" :uuid
                }];
}
```

}

In this way, it works well. But still want to know why cannot directly use [notification.userInfo[@"UUID"] copy] to pass the data. And in Leak, it shows it's a leak cycle, maybe it's a clue to indicate something I missed. If that's the case, in which way cause the UILocalNotification 'notification' and NSNotification 'PopReminder' to retain each other ?

Comment: use stringWithFormat, instead of stringWithString

Comment: Do you need to create a new string? `copy` @Geet don't use `stringWithFormat:` unless you actually have a format to process...

Comment: it is processing an object into string hence at this point you need to use stringWithFormat

Comment: The method `stringWithString` returns an autoreleased object, but that shouldn't matter with ARC. Edit your question to show your code as text with code tags. The leak markers are obscuring the code so I can't tell what those statements are doing.

Comment: @Geet the question says it's a string already. It is not a format, and the OP is not asking for an arbitrary object to be converted into its description. Even if OP was it would be better to call `description` explicitly that to use a format of `@"%@"`. `stringWithFormat` is probably one of the most abused and misused methods in cocoa...

Comment: was having the same issue once, using stringWithFormat solved it.

Comment: Why are you making explicitly making a new string anyway?  Just assign `uuid` as a reference to the string in the dictionary.

Comment: @Geet I tried to use stringWithFormat , still the same result

Comment: @Wain copy also not working

Comment: @Paulw11 I have already tried to directly assign uuid in dictionary, but it still point that string has leak problem

Answer (score 0):

There's zero need to do any reprocessing on the `userInfo` passed in. You can just pass it on directly.

In the meantime, Instruments is telling you that the object created there is eventually leaked. That means someone who catches the `PopReminder` is causing the object to leak. Investigate there. While there is zero need for your arbitrary `[NSString stringWithString:]`, it's not invalid.

The following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"PopReminder"
         object:nil
         userInfo:notification.userInfo];
    }
}
```

... is a perfect, complete version of the method you provide.

Comment: I also think it may irrelevant with NSString method, but has something todo with the receiver of that notification. I will investigate that. Thanks.